# Nesting a react app inside an iframe with routes

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom, iframe

Im having an issue with some app that someone wrote before me with react.
many of the components are styled with inner height & width calculations, getBoundingClientRect , etc.
I now need to add a button that is moving the entire app to the third bottom of the screen.

So my idea was to put the app inside an iframe and to see how good/bad it will look like.
the problam is that i cannot find a way to run my app only in the iframe on the bottom, anyone have an idea how to do it ?

thanks

Comment: What is the issue you are facing running the route inside an iFrame?

Comment: I dont know where to put the iFrame itself, if i put it inside the app component im getting a loop of nested app